# Confusion related to the gradient of the sum of a smooth and non-smooth function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have this confusion related to gradient. Let my function

$f(x) = g(x) + h(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a differentiable function and $h(x)= \lambda\|x\|_1$

$g(x)$ is differentiable but $\|x\|_1$ is not at $x=0$. I found out that gradient of $f(x)$ for $x=0$ is

$$\operatorname{sign}(\operatorname{grad}(g(x)))\max(|\operatorname{grad}(g(x))|-\lambda,0)$$

I didn't get how this formula was derived. Any suggestions? I was actually reading this [paper](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/sustik/papers/invcov.pdf) where they have mentioned

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your notation? What is the domain of these functions? Also, if $f$ was differentiable (in the classical sense) then $h$ would also be differentiable by linearity...

Comment: $f$ doesn't have a gradient at $x=0$, so it's not clear what you mean.  (Also, what does $x^2$ mean when $x$ is a vector?)

Comment: Yea, your notation is very unclear. It appears that $x$ is a vector, but then how are you squaring a vector? Or is $x$ a scalar? In which case, why are you taking the 1-norm of a scalar?